# Log into Webserver from Iphone App?

Tags: php, iphone, mysql, database, post

I have a server with mysql information stored on it. Now i need my Iphone application to be able to log in to a account and update information stored in the the database. So i was wondering, what would be the best way to go about this?
Shall i just use POST to send data to a PHP script and then echo a response for wether the user can login or not(The username and password match) ?

It's just this seems unsecure, also do i need to create some kind of session once the log in stage has been completed?

I have never done this before, so would be really grateful of any help!

Thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

You described the common way to do it. You need some sort of a webserivce you can "talk" with. It's done in the way you post the data to the webserivce, the webserivce (e.g. written in PHP) opens a connection to the database and returns wether the request/login was successful.

If you just send the password in clear text, than it's unsecure you are right. I use two things to make the communication more secure.

1. SSL:  If possible make a secure connections. But it's possible that you do not have the option to connect through ssl.
2. Password hashing: You can at least hash the password. In a normal case the username is public in an application, but the password isn't. A hashing function is function that returns a string that looks a little bit random to humans. Hash functions are one way functions. There's no way to go back to the original string (if you don't have a few super computers and a few hundred years of time). So once you retrieved a hashed password within your webservice, just hash the password in the database too and compare them. A string always returns the same hash if you use the same hash function. Common hash functions are: [MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) or the [SHA familiy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Hash_Algorithm)

I hope my answer helps you any further. Perhaps my approach is not the most secure, but until know no one told me anything better. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

For phone apps, desktop app and some web apps this is a common issue. 
Sandro Meier (above) said correctly that if you have SSL access then this is best way to send via a HTTP POST a username and password so anyone else on the network cannot sniff these details.

If you cannot use HTTPS, then I would recommend from your iPhone app.
1. post username + password to the PHP from the iPhone.
2. ON the server in PHP code, check these details, if correct generate some random token eg (KHnkjhasldjfoi&*)  you can do this by using the MD5 hash function in PHP.
3. Save this hash in the db so you know which user you sent it back to. 
4. Now for all other requests from the app to the PHP include this token with the request (in PHP you will need to check this token and if it is valid, then fetch or update data).
5. This way if someone is trying to sniff the connection they dont have access to the users password, they can only steal the token.

If you want to be 99% secure you need to use a HTTPS connection (but HTTPS can be faked, I wrote about this in Computer World).

The pervious person mentioned using a MD5 hash to send the username password, but this also can be hacked (a user could download you app, find the salt to the MD5 hash and that way they could still steal any password). I think the W3C said that they do not recommend encrypting web forms and password pages as it gives a false sense of security because pretty much anything can be decrypted (I think a Quantum computer can even decrypt HTTPs), they recommend using HTTPs as it provides the most security for sending sensitive data.

W3C Passwords in the clear. 
http://www.w3.org/2001/tag/doc/passwordsInTheClear-52

Comment: I like that you are mentioning quantum computers. Once they are fit for everyday use, we need to get really new algorithms for encrypting...